# Vertical dropdown with horizontal submenu allignment

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make a vertical dropdown menu, with horizontal submenus.

But i cant get the submenu to allign with the parent menu.

Currently the menu works like this:

x

x

x

x>

x - x

But i want it to work like this:

x

x

x

x> - x

x

My code is in the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/919qb7u5/

ive tried with all sorts of fixes, with absolute and relative positions, top and bottom spacings.

```
.dropdown-content ul {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i suggest you to use Easy Button & Menu Maker software to make 
Beautiful menus and buttons.
http://www.easymenumaker.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give `position:relative` to `.dropdown-content li`

```
.dropdown-content li {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/919qb7u5/1/)**

Comment: I just now found the error myself.... Why is it that you have to post here before you figure it out